# relacionar dos arrays de distinto tipo en java

Tags: java, array, matrices, relaciones, array-bidimensional

Por favor necesito ayuda. Debo crear un método que consulte el nombre con mayor número de faltas.
Dispongo de estos dos vectores y de la matríz para las faltas.En principio yo lo hice así:

```
String[] nombre = new String[2];
String[] asignaturas = new String[2];
int[][] faltas = new int[2][2];

public void mayorFalta() {

    int mayor;
    mayor = faltas[0][0];

    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<2; j++){
            if(faltas[i][j]> mayor){
                mayor = faltas[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("El alumno con mayor número de faltas es "+mayor);
}
```

Esto me devuelve el valor de la mayor falta pero lo que necesito es que me devuelva el nombre del alumno al que le corresponde dicha falta. No se como asociar la matriz de faltas con el vector de nombres. O sea que no se como hacer para determinar que a esa falta le corresponda ese alumno para así imprimirlo. Gracias !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te propongo una mejor solución, usar `HashMap` y `Map` en conjunto con `ArrayList`, `HashMap` y `Map` son clases que de alguna manera nos permiten crear algo que se conoce como arreglo asociativo en otros lenguajes de programación como `PHP`.

Checa lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Your code here!

        String[] nombre = new String[2];
        String[] asignaturas = new String[2];

        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> faltas = new ArrayList<>();

        //Definimos las faltas
        Map<String, String> falta = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> falta2 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> falta3 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> falta4 = new HashMap<>();

        //Añadimos a las faltas la información
        falta.put("nombre", "Juan");
        falta.put("faltas", "10");

        falta2.put("nombre", "Jose");
        falta2.put("faltas", "2");

        falta3.put("nombre", "Luis");
        falta3.put("faltas", "5");

        falta4.put("nombre", "Lucas");
        falta4.put("faltas", "3");

        //Añadimos todas las faltas a la lista de faltas
        faltas.add(falta);
        faltas.add(falta2);
        faltas.add(falta3);
        faltas.add(falta4);

        mayorFalta(faltas);
    }

    public static void mayorFalta(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> faltas){

        int actualFaltaMayor = -1;
        Map<String, String> informacionPersonaConMayorFalta = new HashMap<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < faltas.size(); i++){
            if(Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas")) > actualFaltaMayor){
                informacionPersonaConMayorFalta = faltas.get(i);
                actualFaltaMayor = Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas"));
            }
        }

        System.out.println(informacionPersonaConMayorFalta);

    }
}
```

Bien, la manera de declarar un Arreglo asociativo usando `Map` y `HashMap` es la siguiente:

```
Map<String, String> nombreVariable = new HashMap<>();
```

Si, se que tiene una sintaxis algo rara pero lo que hay que tener en cuenta es que dentro de los signos mayor y menor que, van a ir los tipos que queremos almacenar, es decir, la primera parte (la clave) debe ser un string y la segunda tambien, pero tambien hubieramos podido hacer lo siguiente, y es totalmente valido:

```
Map<String, Integer> nombreVariable = new HashMap<>();
```

Valido en el sentido de que esto se puede hacer, mas no que te vaya a funcionar en el código actual, ya que decidi hacer nuestro arreglo asociativo para que solo coja pares de cadenas de texto, ya que muchos tipos que están en cadenas pueden ser convertidos luego a otros, por esta razón es mas fácil y mejor usar `<String, String>` así hay mayor flexibilidad en la conversión de tipos.

Ahora bien, un objeto de este tipo:

```
Map<String, String> nombreVariable = new HashMap<>();
```

Tiene unos cuantos métodos principales, pero entre ellos están los metodos `put` y `get`, donde `put` te permite añadir pares de valores a este arreglo asociativo, y `get` te permite obtenerlos por la clave que le diste:

```
falta.put("nombre", "Juan");
```

Como podemos ver el primer valor es "nombre", el segundo es "juan", esto en pocas palabras lo que nos almacena es algo como esto:

```
{"nombre": "Juan"}
```

Para get solo usamos la clave:

```
falta.get("nombre");    //Juan
```

Y no solo eso si no que ademas podemos poner varias claves y valores como lo vemos aquí:

```
//Es el mismo objeto pero con mas pares de valores.
falta.put("nombre", "Juan");
falta.put("faltas", "10");
```

El resultado almacenado:

```
{"nombre": "Juan", "faltas": "10"};
```

Ahora bien, nosotros tambien definimos algo llamado `ArrayList` ArrayList es una clase que permite añadir tantos elementos como necesitemos y removerlos sin necesidad de nosotros especificarles cuantos elementos va a tener, pero eso sí, siempre almacenara un tipo especifico de valores al igual que un ArrayNormal.

Miremos esta parte:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> faltas = new ArrayList<>();
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es definir un arreglo de faltas, es decir, un arreglo dinamico de `Map<String, String>`.

A continuación tenemos el metodo `mayorFalta`, que fue modificado:

```
public static void mayorFalta(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> faltas){

    int actualFaltaMayor = -1;
    Map<String, String> informacionPersonaConMayorFalta = new HashMap<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < faltas.size(); i++){
        if(Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas")) > actualFaltaMayor){
            informacionPersonaConMayorFalta = faltas.get(i);
            actualFaltaMayor = Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas"));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(informacionPersonaConMayorFalta);

}
```

Fue modificado para poder encajar con `ArrayList`, `Map` y `HashMap`, miremos los cambios mas fuertes hechos y los que hay que explicar:

```
public static void mayorFalta(ArrayList<Map<String, String>> faltas){

}
```

Como vemos ahora el metodo esta recibiendo como parametro un `ArrayList` de `Maps` es decir, nuestra lista de faltas.

```
int actualFaltaMayor = -1;
```

Lo usamos para saber cuál es la persona que actualmente tiene menor numero de faltas, va cambiando en el tiempo...

```
Map<String, String> informacionPersonaConMayorFalta = new HashMap<>();
```

Creamos un objeto temporal llamado informacionPersonaConMayorFalta que será el que almacene la información de la persona con la cantidad mas grande de faltas.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < faltas.size(); i++){
        if(Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas")) > actualFaltaMayor){
            informacionPersonaConMayorFalta = faltas.get(i);
            actualFaltaMayor = Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas"));
        }
    }
```

En este ciclo recorremos las `faltas`, como faltas es de tipo `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` es decir, es un `ArrayList`, los ArrayList tienen un metodo llamado `size` que cuando lo invocamos nos devuelve la cantidad de elementos presentes en el `ArrayList`.

```
if(Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas")) > actualFaltaMayor){

}
```

Esta condición nos indica que se debe obtener la falta actual que se esta recorriendo en el ciclo y a esa falta obtener su propiedad "faltas", como es un string, debe convertirse a int para poder ser comparado con el signo `>` luego lo comparamos con la variable `actualFaltaMayor`, en caso de que la condición se cumpla significa que ese elemento es el que actualmente contiene la mayor cantidad de faltas, entonces:

```
informacionPersonaConMayorFalta = faltas.get(i);
actualFaltaMayor = Integer.parseInt(faltas.get(i).get("faltas"));
```

Reemplazamos la información que contenia nuestro `Map` llamado `informacionPersonaConMayorFalta` con el actual que tiene mayor numero de faltas y luego a la `actualFaltaMayor` la dejamos la reemplazamos por el numero que es la actual falta mayor (la cantidad mayor de faltas).

Por ultimo:

```
System.out.println(informacionPersonaConMayorFalta);
```

Imprimimos en consola la información de la persona con mayores faltas.

Aunque si quieres tambien podemos poner al final lo que tenias en tu código, poniendolo entonces así:

```
System.out.println("El alumno con mayor número de faltas es " + informacionPersonaConMayorFalta.get("nombre"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Además de la variable que usas para guardar la falta mayor, puedes agregar una variable para guardar el valor del índice correspondiente a la falta mayor y luego recuperas el nombre usando ese índice:

```
public void mayorFalta() {
    int mayor;
    int indice = 0;
    mayor = faltas[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<2; j++){
            if(faltas[i][j]> mayor){
                mayor = faltas[i][j];
                indice = i;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("El alumno con mayor número de faltas es "+ nombre[indice]);
}
```